# How to access camera (video) on IE 11?

Tags: internet-explorer, camera, webrtc, getusermedia

I need to be able to access the camera. I'm using mediaDevices.getUserMedia and it works good on Chrome, but most of our users use Internet Explorer 11.

I've been reading about these:

```
    webcamjs: https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs
    webrtc adapter: https://github.com/webrtc/adapter
    getUserMedia: https://github.com/addyosmani/getUserMedia.js
```

I've tried them but there are not good examples.
I just need to be able to access the camera on internet explorer 11 which can't possibly be that difficult.

I'd appreciate if some one could provide a concise example.

Comment: Did you get any error while running the example in the IE 11 browser? Which exact code you are trying to test with IE 11 browser? Are you using any polyfill to run the code in the IE 11 browser? I suggest you try to provide any sample code that we can try to test with the IE 11 browser to check for the issue. I can see that you are referring to the webcams. You can visit this link to get the examples. https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs/tree/master/demos

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the getuserMedia working on IE, you have to use webRTC plugin, one such plugin is from temasys.

https://temasys.io/products/temasys-webrtc-plugin/